# How to load Silverlight in IE8 when automating tasks with PowerShell?

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell, powershell-2.0

I am working on a PowerShell script to automate some tasks. The script worked in my test environment, but when I moved to production the script didn't work. I quickly noticed that Silverlight wasn't loading in IE8 in production (the web app just prompted for installing Silverlight).

Initially, this is what the code started with: `$ie = new-object -comobject "InternetExplorer.Application"`

Unfortunately, Silverlight wasn't loading here.

I then tried to load Silverlight in IE8 by doing this (which actually loaded Silverlight): `Start-Process iexplore.exe`

Problem is, I am having trouble capturing the object and then navigating from there... by doing something like: `$ie = Start-Process iexplore.exe` and `$ie.navigate("blah")`

Is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: I did a little more analysis... To simplify this Post, I am looking to launch the 32-bit version of Internet Explorer... It appears that I am openeing the 64-bit version (which doesn't load Silverlight).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to start 32bits version of IE8 why don't you just launch your script with 32 Bits version of PowerShell I mean : `%SystemRoot%\syswow64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`

As far as I understand UAC helping it will find the 32Bits COM object in the 32Bits part of the registry.

Comment: Thanks. That appears to work... My next question is: When I run this script via the command line, IE pops up (32-bit version) and executes the tasks as expected... When I execute as a Task Schedule, the job runs, but I don't actually see the browser through the UI. Is that expected? Is the OS still executing this job virtually? Unfortunately, I need the browser to actually open.

Comment: I just realized that I have to run the task "only when the user is logged in" - interactive tasks can't be run when the user is logged off. Thanks.